# Conditional expected value with table of joint distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I have the following table of random values $x_1$ and $x_2$

[image]

I need to compute $\mathbb{E}(x_2\mid (x_1 - 1)^2 \ge 1)$. I have done it. However, there is some doubt.

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(x_2\mid (x_1 - 1)^2 \ge 1) &= \mathbb{E}(x_2\mid x_1 = -1\parallel x_1 = 0 \parallel x_1 = 2 ) =\\
& = \sum_j \mathbb{E}(x_2\mid x_1 = b_j ) P (x_1 = b_j ) = \\
&= \sum_j \left( \sum_i a_i P(x_2 = a_i \mid x_1 = b_j)\right) P (x_1 = b_j ) =\\
&= \sum_j \left( \sum_i a_i \frac{P(x_2 = a_i, x_1 = b_j)}{P (x_1 = b_j )}\right) P (x_1 = b_j ) = \\
&= \sum_j \sum_i a_i P(x_2 = a_i, x_1 = b_j) = \\
&= \sum_i a_i \sum_j  P(x_2 = a_i, x_1 = b_j)
\end{align}
$$
where $\parallel$ is logic ''OR''

And that's all. However, I am almost sure that I need to get $P(x_1 = b_j)$ in the final expression and I don't like that this value just got reduced. Do I have mistake here?

Edit: I don't understand where I have problem with my soution. Is it correct: $$\mathbb{E} (A \mid B \parallel C \parallel D) = \mathbb{E} (A \mid B) P (B) + \dots $$
and Is it correct? 
$$P(A \mid  B \parallel C \parallel D ) = P (A \mid B) + P (A \mid C) + \dots$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are doing.

You should simply go for finding: $$\mathsf E(x_2\mid(x_1-1)^2\geq1)=$$$$-2\mathsf P(x_2=-2\mid(x_1-1)^2\geq1)-\mathsf P(x_2=-1\mid(x_1-1)^2\geq1)+2\mathsf P(x_2=2\mid(x_1-1)^2\geq1)$$

Here e.g.: $$\mathsf P(x_2=-2\mid(x_1-1)^2\geq1)=\mathsf P(x_2=-2\wedge (x_1-1)^2\geq1)/\mathsf P((x_1-1)^2\geq1)=$$$$(0.05+0.2+0.15)/(0.3+0.28+0.21)$$

Comment: I see no problem in your solution (and it gives the same result besides of one denominator). But, I don't understand where I have problem with my soution. Is it correct: $\mathbb{E} (A \mid B || C || D) = \mathbb{E} (A \mid B) P (B) + \dots $ 
and Is it correct? 
$P(A \mid  B || C || D ) = P (A \mid B) + P (A \mid C) + \dots$

Comment: I am not familiar with your notation. Is "$B||C||D$" standing for "$B\text{ or }C\text{ or }D$"? Or this maybe under the extra condition that $B,C,D$ are mutually disjoint?

Comment: sorry, it is logic "OR"

Comment: oh, I see and without the second condition I should divide this sum with $P (P \cup C\cup D)$. What about expectation $\mathbb{E} (A \mid B \cup C \cup D)$? Does it equal to $\mathbb{E}(A \mid B) P(B) + \mathbb{E}(A \mid C) P(C) + \mathbb{E}(A \mid D) P(D)$?

Comment: It is not correct that $P(A\mid B\cup C\cup D)=P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid C)+P(A\mid D)$. Work out the general rule $P(E\mid F)=P(E\cap F)/P(F)$ to find out why it is not correct.

Comment: If $A$ is an event then you cannot speak of an expectation.

Comment: $A$ is random value in that expression

Comment: Wait, you deleted your comment. Does that mean that the expression about probabilities is completely wrong?

Comment: Then $\mathbb E(A\mid B\cup C\cup D)=\sum_a aP(A=a\mid B\cup C\cup D)$. Yes, forget about my former comment. I made a typo there, sorry.

Comment: I know those definitions actually. I just wonder can I open this expected value from another side... from condinitional side, not from usual $\sum a P(x=a)$ side.

Comment: There is a rule $\mathbb EA=\mathbb E(A|B)P(B)+\mathbb E(A|C)P(C)+\mathbb E(A\mid D)P(D)$ if the $B,C,D$ are disjoint events with $P(B\cup C\cup D)=1$. Maybe you are confused with that one.